# Scrapy-splash no results at "Server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8050"

Tags: python, docker, hostname, scrapy-splash

I'm on Windows 10 Home Edition using Docker tool box (my BIOS configuration doesn't allow me to install Linux)

When I run

```
docker run -it -p 8050:8050 --rm scrapinghub/splash
```

I receive the log message `Server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8050`, as it should be in normal cases. But when I go to the address at my Chrome, the only thing that returns is `ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID`, not possible to access the page.

---

**I have tried the following solutions** to this problem:

1. Changing the `SPLASH_URL` on my `settings.py` according to my Docker IP adress;
2. Adding new ports to my docker run, such as `5023:5023` and `8051:8051`.

I imagine that this is the kind of problem which I need to investigate its caused by myself. But I have tried everything that I could find on the Internet.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is an invalid IP address. It means "all interfaces". You should point your browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8050`.

Comment: Interesting. Now I've tried `http://127.0.0.1:8050` and it returned `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. Is this the Firewall? But why `http://127.0.0.1:8050`? Should `127.0.0.1` be the docker IP?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the `localhost`, i.e. your own computer. To be clear, you are running the Chrome on the same machine as the docker instance aren't you?

Comment: Yes, I'm running Chrome on the same machine I'm running the scrapinghub/splash image.

Comment: Docker networking on Windows is a bit, well, shaky. I remember connecting to a docker instance from the host PC wasn't being supported in the past. Try using a different browser and/or connecting from a different PC or your mobile device (using the LAN IP address of your machine).

Comment: Definitely gonna try it, and come back with some results (if any). Thanks

Comment: If it's Docker Toolbox, you need the `docker-machine ip` address, usually 192.168.99.100.

Comment: The `docker-machine ip` worked perfectly! The `ip` is diferrent, but I could get through terminal. And I have changed the `SPLASH_URL` on `settings.py` as well. How can I highlight it? Also, thanks for both of you who helped me understand the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gonna write the right answer, thanks to the users [Selcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011147/selcuk), for explaning some technical terms, and [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze), for giving me the final solution.

---

Since we are using the Docker Toolbox, we need to use our `docker-machine ip`.
Go to your terminal and type:

```
docker-machine ip
```

Now that you have the right `ip`, go to your `settings.py` and set

```
SPLASH_URL = http://[docker-machine ip]:8050
```

And you're good to go!

Answer (score 3):

**You don't need to change any settings.**

If you launch docker terminal, it shows the correct ip address at the very first, right after the whale drawing.

```
                       ##         .
              ## ## ##        ==
           ## ## ## ## ##    ===
       /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
  ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
       \______ o           __/
         \    \         __/
          \____\_______/

docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.102
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com
```

So in my case the ip was 192.168.99.102.

If I visit 192.168.99.102:8050 on chrome, splash works.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but it has been helpfull for me. I add another way to get the IP address, without docker-machine.

With the container ID you can get the IP address with:

`sudo docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' CONTAINER ID`

To get the container ID use : `sudo docker ps`

You can also use the container name instead of the ID